# Asp Net Core 2.1 - Can we use ConfigurationBuilder in Startup ctor?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

Say I set two `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT` called `uat` and `prod`.
I'd like to use `appsettings.uat.json` and `appsettings.prod.json`.

In prior asp net core version the `Startup` ctor had a `ConfigurationBuilder` that I could change like that to do what I want:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile(
            $"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json",
            optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

But the new `Startup` ctor is simpler in 2.1:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
```

Will I ommit "things" that are automamagically done by this new ctor if I use the previous one?

UPDATE

My `Startup` ctor above seems to work fine with 2.1 and I don't "feel" I lost any "magic".

Here is the `Program` class requested in comments:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Comment: question updated

Comment: If what you have seems to work fine, then stick with it. The only real difference with your approach is that you're just ignoring the default configuration set up by `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` - further down the line, if you were to retrieve an instance of `IConfiguration` from DI, it might not be *your* version (rather, it'll be the the one that's usually passed into your `Startup` ctor).

Comment: The alternative is to customise the `IConfiguration` that gets passed into your `Startup` ctor, which is done using `ConfigureAppConfiguration` in your Program.cs.